# Docker for Windows Error - No activity detected on VM, aborting

Tags: windows, visual-studio, vmware-workstation, linux-containers, docker-desktop

I have Docker Desktop for Windows :-

Version 2.0.0.3 (31259)
Channel: stable
Build: 8858db3
Engine: 18.09.2

I am running a Windows 10 virtual machine in VMWare Workstation 15.0.4 with 4 cores and 12GB RAM, guest Windows 10 version is 1809 (17763.379).

To create the problem:-
Start Docker Desktop
Switch to Linux Container

After a while the following error is returned:-
No activity detected on VM, aborting
…(rest removed coz it wouldn’t let me post with it in, but it is the same as all the others)

I have seen this issue in many messages and I have tried as many of the recommended solutions i can find (using 1 core not 4, resetting to factory defaults, uninstall/reinstall, elevated powershell windows feature activation, checking hostname consistency, etc etc etc), but I still get the same error. I see a lot of the messages just don’t have a solution other than upgrade to the new version, but I have installed the latest version and the problem persists. As with the other posters, Windows containers work fine.

There doesn’t seem to be an explanation either for why this happens, does anyone know what is causing this issue?

I would guess that because there are so many end users that have tried different solutions and with all the mixed results from those solutions that this is not a simple single-root-cause issue otherwise i am sure i would have my setup working by now (i have spent two days tearing my hair out over this!).

Bit of background - this vm is my development vm and my main ide is visual studio. i do not have the option of installing docker on my host as it seems to only be recognised by visual studio if it is installed locally. so if there are any devs out there using visual studio in a virtual machine that develop with the vs container tools and linux containers (linux ones fail coz they are in hyper-v, windows ones work fine coz they use native win10 container support) that have any tips for me to get this running, i would really appreciate it :)

I know that docker have stated that running docker desktop in a vm is unsupported, but i bet there are loads of devs out there who use vm's to develop in and i am hoping someone has figured this out....

Comment: Same issue with version 2.1.0.5 (40693) For me, it happens only in linux mode with graph value is set on daemon json.